# Amount Is Invalid. Amount Must Be In Cents

Tags: expresso-store, ee2, payment-gateway, omnipay, payu

This is the first time I am getting this error. I am currently using PayU as payment gateway and integrated this by using Omnipay in expresso store in my EE2 project. In my request object that I need to send to PayU I need to times the amount by 100 to convert this into cents and I am doing this.

The error I get is: `{"store_payment_error":"Amount is invalid. Amount must be in cents"}`

I got this error when I had an order amount of R22 293.36. Is this too big an amount for the gateway or store to handle? I am sure this shouldn't be the problem? I have over 200 orders that I tested already, but the first time I am getting this error?

Comment: Seems to be every time an order is greater than R10 000 I get this error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FIXED:** I am using the function `$this->getAmountInteger();` where I am building the request object to send the info over to the payment gateway and timed this by 100 to convert it into cents. **BE AWARE** that this function already times the order/cart amount by 100, hence there is no need to have it as `$this->getAmountInteger() * 100;`